# Auditing db-rollbacks

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I'm wondering if there is a build-in/standard way to audit db-rollbacks in an Spring (3.1), Hibernate/JPA environment.

Greatful for any hints.

Thanks
Jonny

Comment: Are you working with hibernate?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I thing enabling "hibernate.show_sql" and using the logging configuration

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG, SQL_APPENDER
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate.SQL=false
```

should help you log SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor rollbacks you can setup logging for [org.hibernate.transaction](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/transaction/package-summary.html) package

```
13:50:28,597 DEBUG http-8080-1 org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - begin
13:50:28,657 DEBUG http-8080-1 org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - current    autocommit status: true
13:50:28,657 DEBUG http-8080-1 org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - disabling autocommit
13:50:28,714 DEBUG http-8080-1 org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - commit
13:50:28,773 DEBUG http-8080-1 org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
13:50:28,828 DEBUG http-8080-1 org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - committed JDBC Connection
```

If you want to take some action upon transaction rollback, you can use AOP to create an aspect and map it to org.hibernate.Transaction.rollback() method execution.

```
@Aspect
public class TransactionMonitoringAspect {

@Before("execution(* org.hibernate.Transaction.rollback())")
public void deviceLoad(String deviceSerial) {
  //do something here
}

}
```

you can use various annotations from org.aspectj.lang.annotation package to execute various methods around rollback() method.